# Python/Sklearn - IndexError - Index out of bounds

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run a kNN classifier across my dataset using 10-fold CV. I have some experience with models in WEKA but struggling to transfer this over to Sklearn.

Below is my code

```
filename = 'train4.csv'
names = ['attribut names are here']
dataframe = read_csv(filename, names=names)
array = dataframe.values
X = array[:,0:47]
Y = array[:,47]
num_folds = 10
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7)
model = KNeighborsClassifier()
results = cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold)
print(results.mean())
```

I get the error

```
>IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-8d9596c3368b> in <module>()
      4 array = dataframe.values
      5 X = array[:,0:47]
----> 6 Y = array[:,47]
      7 num_folds = 10
      8 kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7)

> IndexError: index 47 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 47
```

In my CSV the 47th attribute is the target label - hence the 48 (am I wrong here?).

I am running pandas/sklearn in Jupyter notebook.

Thanks

Comment: does your CSV have column names and what is the column name of the target `y` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'train4.csv'
names = ['attribut names are here']
target_col_name = 'name_of_your_target_column'

df = pd.read_csv(filename, names=names)

num_folds = 10
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7)
model = KNeighborsClassifier()
results = cross_val_score(model,
                          df.drop(target_col_name, axis=1), 
                          df[target_col_name],
                          cv=kfold)
print(results.mean())
```

Comment: Hi buddy, thanks for the reply. Using this code I replace both 'target_col_name' with my column name between ''. I receive the error 'ValueError: labels ['mix1_instrument'] not contained in axis'

Comment: @Gareth, can you post an output of `print(df.columns.tolist())`?

Comment: I found a spelling error in my column names. Thanks. I now receive a value error, i'm assuming it's because I have two attributes with data type of 'object'. How can I rectify this?

Comment: @Gareth, well, it's another question and it should be asked separately ... ;-)